# Не соеденяет с Unity Remote 5

Tags: android, android-studio, unity3d, 3d, unity3d-android

нужно проверить acceleration на телефоне, ну что бы постоянно не скачивать, решил через Unity Editor сделать, но не соединяет, вот что я сделал (скриншоты):

1) Скачал JDK, SDK, NDK, и подключил к Unity;
2) Скачал на телефон Unity Remote 5 (у меня версия 5.2.4);
3) Поставил в параметрах разработчика (и при этом включил) подключение чего-то там при подключении USB;
4) Подключил USB. Зашел в программу Unity Remote 5 и на компе запустил игру (имеется ввиду что игру при разработке в Unity);

И результата нет, может кто знает что я не так сделал? При этом USB Driver Google установил в SDK;

Скриншоты:  http://uploads.ru/?g=lp5Is.jpg